# ¿Cuál es la mejor opción para cargar imágenes: MySQL o directo al servidor?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy en el proceso de desarrollo de un directorio de contactos, este necesita mostrar imágenes (pequeña galería) por contacto, pero no sé cuál sea la mejor opción de hacerlo, guardarlas directo en la base de datos o subirlas directo al servidor.

Comment: ¿Tiene sentido ser duplicado de una pregunta que me cerraron por 'estar basada en opiniones'?

Answer (score 0):

Pues es un antiguo debate. Yo creo que depende de las características de tu proyecto. Cada opción tiene su pros y sus contras. En los dos casos se suben al servidor, en la base de datos tendrás las facilidades que ofrecen las bases de datos: si los guardas en el sistema de archivos, pues tendrás todas las facilidades del manejo de archivo. Así de primeras...

**Almacenamiento en BD**:

A favor:

- Simplificas el backup de los datos y las imágenes.
- Haces más sencilla la portabilidad de los datos.

En contra:

- Sobrecargas las transacciones en el servidor de bases de datos.

**Almacenamiento en sistema de archivos.**

A favor:

- Aligeras las carga del servidor de bases datos.
- Te beneficias de las apis de manejo de archivos para el manejo archivos.

En contra:

- Dos etapas en el backup de los datos (backup de datos en BD y datos del file system).
- Limitaciones del sistema de archivos para las imágenes (aunque hoy en día no sería mucho problema, si habláramos de vídeo desde luego XD)

Yo personalmente siempre guardo las imágenes en el sistema de archivos y la BD lo que guardo son los paths. Más bien lo hago por costumbre pues todos los frameworks web que conozco tienden a hacerlo así. Será por ser lo más eficiente... aunque cada caso siempre es un mundo ;-)

*En la versión en inglés hubo un intenso debate: [Debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)